# How do I only copy files from one drive to another if the files I want aren't currently there?

Tags: backup

I have a directory with a lot of images in it. I have a flash drive where I also have many of the same pictures. But let's say that I updated my directory to have even MORE pictures, but wanted only the ones that were added to said directory to be saved to the flash drive ALONG with the other files.

This all needs to be done from within the command line if possible.

Comment: `rsync` is the command-line tool for this.

Comment: I've looked into rsync but it's confusing me. Can you give me any idea for the syntax for an operation like this?

Comment: something like: `rsync -a /home/mydir /media/myusb/photos`

Answer (score 2):

ok let's make this an answer. `rsync` is the command-line tool for this. So you need something along these lines:

```
rsync -a /home/mydir /media/myusb/photos
```

see `man rsync` for full details. The `-a` option gives you a subset of the most commonly used options - it is 'archive mode' equivalent to -rlptgoD. This would copy the contents of /home/mydir to /media/myusb/photos, it wouldn't bother to copy any files that were already present and identical on the destination.

Comment: Adding "/" onto "/home/mydir" may be closer to your intent.